# clicking pixel relitive to location based on color. no set X,Y value

Tags: python-3.x, image, automation, pixel

I have a script that I already have able to locate a image. then from the center of that image will move the mouse position to a location relative to that image.

What I am trying to do now is have the mouse click that location only if it matches the RGB value. Without having a set X,Y value because the target image and pixel could move on screen.

Is there a simple code that could detect if the pixel the mouse is over matches the RGB value without having a X,Y value? Then click if the RGB value is right?

Evey tutorial just gives me how to find X,Y position and color of a set location.
I'm am extremity new to python and never wrote script before so please keep in mind.
Thank you for any help you can provide.

```
from pyautogui import*
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con


time.sleep(2)
while 1:
    time.sleep(2)
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('boss monster.png', confidence=0.8) !=None:
        pyautogui.moveTo((pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('boss monster.png', grayscale=True, confidence=0.8)))
        pyautogui.moveRel(361, 209, duration= 0.5)
```

the next function i want is to click mouse location only if RGB value matches. without having a set X,Y location
this is where I'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pyautogui.position()` it will return a [tuple](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp) and you will be able to index it and assign it to variables, after that we can use `pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor` to check if the cursor is currently on the pixel of desired rgb color:

```
import pyautogui
import time 

while True:
    # Prevent a ton of output (you can delete this if you want, it was only needed for testing)
    time.sleep(1)
    # Get current location of your cursor
    cursor_location = pyautogui.position()

    # pyautogui.position() will return a tuple with x and y coordinates,
    # this specific tuple contains Point(x=1028, y=228) . To get those values
    # from the tuple you can just index it like this:

    # we get the first value [0] which is the x coordinate of the cursor and  [1] which is the y coordinate
    x, y = cursor_location[0], cursor_location[1]
    # if the rgb color matches the pixel your cursor is pointing at:
    if pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(x, y, (0, 0, 0)): #instead of 0,0,0 put your rgb value
        print("black found")
        pyautogui.click()
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll look at that when I get home and give it a try.

Comment: thanks, had to mess with it a little but it worked. i wanted to post the result of code but didn't show right so didn't